# UISwipeGestureRecognizer and UIScrollView

Tags: iphone, ios, uiscrollview, uigesturerecognizer

I have a vertical scrollview(no horizontal scrolling possible) and my tab bar is hidden by default. However, you can, by swiping up in the bottom area of the screen, pull the tab bar up.(content needs a lot of vertical space) 
There is my dilemma: I want to be able to detect a swipe up gesture in the bottom area of my scrollview, without the scrollview scrolling down. So I was thinking of putting a transparent view over that bottom area, to only detect that swipe up. But this has the problem that, although that view is transparent, all my touch events are intercepted by that view and are not forwarded to the scrollview.

Is it possible to only forward taps to my scrollview, so I am still able to, for example, press buttons that are currently in the bottom area of my scrollview?

Strange problem I know, but I wasn't able to find a similar problem with a working solution.

My scrollview code:

```
scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 30, 320, self.view.frame.size.height - 50)];
scrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = YES;
scrollView.tag = 0;
scrollView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
scrollView.delegate = self;
scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 1.0;
scrollView.clipsToBounds = NO;
scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 1.0;
scrollView.scrollEnabled = YES;
scrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;
scrollview.contentSize = CGMakeSize(320, xxxx);
```

My transparent view code:

```
UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeUp = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc]
                                      initWithTarget:self
                                      action:@selector(showTabBar)];
swipeUp.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionUp;
UIView *swipeLayer = [[swipeLayer alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(30, self.view.frame.size.height - 80, 260, 40)];
[hideButtonSwipeActions addGestureRecognizer:swipeUp];
[hideButtonSwipeActions setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
//[hideButtonSwipeActions setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];

...
[swipeUp release];
```

Thank you very much for any help :)

Comment: I don't really get what you're asking. You want a transparent view on the bottom of the scrollview, so that you can swipe on it?

Comment: Kind of. I have a fullscreen scrollview, which only scrolls vertically. Now imagine you want to be able to implement a swipe up gesture only for the bottom of the window. So I put a transparent view over the scrollview to receive the swipe gesture, but it doesn't forward normal touch events to the scrollview - thats the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe if you use the coordinates of the touch (0,480) to track the View bottom ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the bottom UIView's userInteractionEnabled property to NO? It should still allow your swipe recognizer to work, however it should stop the view from swallowing normal touches.